HotChocolate.Types.Filters Null Reference issue
I use GraphQL HotChocolate nuget (HotChocolate.AspNetCore and HotChocolate.Types.Filters) of version 11.0.9 (need to use quite old, but reproduced even in 13.9.14) with enabled filtering capabilities for collections.
In general, filtering works well, but for some queries it causes NullReferenceException during filtering (middleware stage).
Bit details (I've created a small project to reproduce this issue):
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ItemSetting ItemSetting { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}

public class ItemSetting
{
    public int Data { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[UseFiltering]
public IEnumerable<Item> GetItems()
{
    return [
        new Item
        {
            Id = 1,
            ItemSetting = new ItemSetting
            {
                Data = 123
            },
            Categories = [ new Category
            {
                Name = "Cat1"
            }]
        },
        new Item
        {
            Id = 2,
            ItemSetting = null,
            Categories = [ new Category
            {
                Name = "Cat2"
            }]
        }
    ];
}

And query, which causes the error:

query { items(where: {categories_some: {name: "Cat1"}, itemSetting: {data: 123}}) { id itemSetting { data } categories { name } } }

Error itself:

{ "errors": [ { "message": "Unexpected Execution Error", "locations": [ { "line": 2, "column": 3 } ], "path": [ "items" ], "extensions": { "message": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.", "stackTrace": "   at lambda_method83(Closure, Item)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator 1.MoveNext()\r\n   at HotChocolate.Execution.Processing.ResolverTask.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.b__0()\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task 1.InnerInvoke()\r\n   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location ---\r\n   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location ---\r\n   at HotChocolate.Execution.Processing.ResolverTask.ExecuteResolverPipelineAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at HotChocolate.Execution.Processing.ResolverTask.TryExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)" } } ], "data": { "items": null } }

The strange thing is, if I change the order of filter condition, no issue:

items(where: { itemSetting: {data: 123}, categories_some: {name: "Cat1"}})

I've bit investigated, and looks like QueryableFilterVisitor (from nuget) creates Expression for IQueriable with wrong order (first it checks value of downData, and then it checks downItemSetting object is not null).
I have a small project to reproduce this issue if needed (https://github.com/olu-lebara/FilterIssueTest).
Please help to find out any fix. Because workaround to change order is not applicable in my case (clients do not know about this issue).

PR with possible fix (for test repo): https://github.com/olu-lebara/FilterIssueTest/pull/1
Basically, only 1 line changed in inherited class (in private method, that's why need to override 2 protected methods with no changes) and forced to use custom visitor.

You can change nullability for data property, not for itemSetting property (what do I mean: https://github.com/RenatV/FilterIssueTest) or use new extra fied as itemSetting is null mark and check them (itemSetting property also must be notNullable         public ItemSetting ItemSetting { get; set; } = new();).

Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately I cannot change model like this - service is already on PROD and affected property value should be null in case if data is not relevant for such kind of object.

I've added some details on question on GitHub - https://github.com/ChilliCream/graphql-platform/discussions/7850
